# trouble with array of CGColor

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, cgcolor

Setting my UIView .backgroundColor from an item in my CGColor array causes build error:
"Type of expression is ambiguous without more context"
(at bottom of code)

I want to display UIView rectangles and control the color of each.

Here's the code -- build error at bottom..

```
class ViewController: UIViewController 
{
// the array of UIView's, one for each rectangle:  
            static var map_sectors_UIView: [UIView] = [] 

 override func viewDidLoad()    
 {
// init the UIView array:
                for map_sector_index in 0...App.total_map_sectors-1
                {
                    let new_UIView = UIView()
                    new_UIView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false //You need to call this property so the image is added to your view
                    ViewController.map_sectors_UIView[ map_sector_index ] = new_UIView 
                }

            super.viewDidLoad()

// Add the subviews:
            for map_sector_index in 0...App.total_map_sectors-1
            {
                view.addSubview( ViewController.map_sectors_UIView[ map_sector_index ] )
            }
. . .
// init each UIView rectangle:
                    ViewController.map_sectors_UIView[ map_sector_index ].frame = CGRect(    x: map_sector_column * App.sector_width_pix,
                                                                                             y: map_sector_row * App.sector_height_pix, 
                                                                                             width: App.sector_width_pix, 
                                                                                             height: App.sector_height_pix )
ViewController.map_sectors_UIView[ map_sector_index ].backgroundColor = .green

. . .


 class App
 {
            static var sector_colors_array: [CGColor] = []
. . .
    static func init_class()
    {

// Declare array of colors for the UIView rectangles:
        sector_colors_array = [CGColor]( repeating: UIColor.black.cgColor,
                                    count: total_map_sectors )
}

. . .

// Display all the rectangles:
        DispatchQueue.main.sync
        {    
                ViewController.map_sectors_UIView[ sector_index ].backgroundColor = sector_colors_array[ sector_index ]

.......... gets build error: "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context"
```

Comment: Why is everything `static`?

Comment: Why are you surprised? You've said yourself `sector_colors_array` is an array of CGColor. But a view's `backgroundColor` is _not_ a CGColor. So the line in question makes to sense to the compiler (or to a human).

Comment: Adding on to what @matt said, `backgroundColor` takes in a `UIColor`, not `CGColor`

Answer (score -1):

Thanks, Matt.  Easy to fix.  Just replaced references to CGColor with UIColor.